# log4j not writing messages to file

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, log4j, slf4j

Looked at quite a few examples on this and have seen some confusing stuff. Here is the log4j.xml file

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
  <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender"> 
    <param name="Target" value="System.out"/> 
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %c{1} - %m%n"/> 
    </layout> 
  </appender>

  <appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
       <param name="append" value="false" />
       <param name="maxFileSize" value="1000KB" />
       <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="5" />
       <!-- For Tomcat -->
       <param name="file" value="${catalina.home}/logs/demandManage.log" />
       <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" 
            value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
       </layout>
    </appender>

  <logger name="com.xxx.demand.domain.data" additivity="true">
    <level value="debug" /> 
    <appender-ref ref="file"/>
  </logger>

  <logger name="com.xxx.rita.serviceserver.controller.AbstractRestController" additivity="true">
    <level value="debug" />  
    <appender-ref ref="file"/>
    <appender-ref ref="console" /> 
  </logger>

  <logger name="com.xxx.dao.AbstractDAOImpl" additivity="true">
    <level value="debug" />  
    <appender-ref ref="file"/>
    <appender-ref ref="console" /> 
  </logger>


  <logger name="org.hibernate" >
    <level value="warn" />
    <appender-ref ref="file"/>
  </logger>

  <root> 
    <priority value ="warn" /> 
    <appender-ref ref="console" /> 
    <appender-ref ref="file"/>
  </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

In my java class:

```
package com.xxx.dao;

public abstract class AbstractDAOImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> implements AbstractDAO<T,ID>{
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(com.xxx.dao.AbstractDAOImpl.class);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T read(ID id){
        T response = (T) getCurrentSession().get(clazz, id);
        if(response==null){
            logger.error(RiskTaker.name.get()+ " tried to load " + clazz + " of " +id);
            throw new RuntimeException("hibernate object did not exist");
        }
        return response;
    }

}
```

So when I am hitting the logger.error message with this configuration, nothing is going to the demandManage.log file or the console. I don't see what's wrong. When I had root set to debug, hibernate of course practically fills up that log file so it does work. 
Is there a difference between using level vs priority? Like a slfj4 vs appache logger? The root sets priority but the child loggers are using level. 
I am starting tomcat in debug mode and know I am hitting those logger.error statements but the file remains empty. May be I need to flush to it right away? 
I previously had the logger in the xml file as fully qualified and in the java class as just class name only but fixing that did nothing. I am wondering what I am missing. Thank you in advance.

Comment: When it "practically fills up that log file" does your error message also appear among the logged entries?

Comment: How I resolved this is I was using slf4j in class to set up logger and then i switched to apache log4j and the file started to fill up. I don't realize exactly what the mismatch is there.

Comment: used Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger opposed to Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger

Comment: No it did not include the entries I was logging. This was all in tomcat and the Logger I was originally was using was slf4j and when I switched to using Apache logger, the messages were there.